# Why isn't the variable available?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, puppet, ruby

**Background**

I would like to apply [this](http://www.allgoodbits.org/articles/view/33) idea of having a `common` class that includes all the specific info about my setup.

So I have created `/etc/puppet/modules/common/manifests/init.pp` with

```
class common { include common::data }
class common::data { $ntpServerList = [ 'ntp51.ex.com','ntp3.ex.com' ] }
```

and installed [this](https://github.com/saz/puppet-ntp) ntp module and have created a node like so

```
node testip {
  include myconfig::ntpp
}
```

**Problem**

`/etc/puppet/modules/myconfig/manifests/init.pp` contains

```
class myconfig::ntpp {
  include common
  class {'ntp':
      server_list => $ntpServerList
#          server_list => ['ntp.ex.com']    # this works
  }
}
```

and I would have expected that `$ntpServerList` would be available, but it isn't. The error is

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed to parse template ntp/ntp.conf.erb:
  Filepath: /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/templatewrapper.rb
  Line: 64
  Detail: Could not find value for 'server_list' at /etc/puppet/modules/ntp/templates/ntp.conf.erb:25
 at /etc/puppet/modules/ntp/manifests/init.pp:183 on node testip
```

**Question**

Can anyone figure out what is wrong with my `myconfig::ntpp` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fully qualify your variables; `$common::data::ntpServerList`.

As it is, your code is looking for a variable called `ntpServerList` in the local scope (`$myconfig::ntpp::ntpServerList`) which doesn't exist, so it falls back to the top scope (`$::ntpServerList`) where it also doesn't exist.

See [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/variables.html#variables) for more details.

Comment: Very impressive! It worked!